# Invalid JSON primitive: _search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

Can some please help me in resolving this issue.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Invalid JSON primitive: _search. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: _search.

```
gridtable.jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        url: Configuration.Endpoint.user + '/Url',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        gridview: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        colNames: [],
        colModel: [],
        jsonReader: { root: "Data.rows", total: "Data.total", records: "Data.records", repeatitems: true, cell: "", id: "0" },
        pager: '#pager',
        loadonce: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        headertitles: true,
        //Getting Error here in xhr
        loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                alert("Load incomplete error");
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(st);
                console.log(err);
            },
```

Comment: Show your server code

Comment: `colModel` and `colNames` can't be empty!